# devise_cas_authenticatable with dynamic cas_base_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cas

Using Rails, Devise and devise_cas_authenticatable, I want to use a different CAS server depending on some internal configuration.

Since cas_base_url is set up in an initializer, the value is re-written like this in a before filter:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.cas_base_url="my_custom_variable_cas_server"
end
```

As soon as the before_filter is called, and then :authenticate_user!, in the first run the custom cas server is set, but after that it's cached or something and never modified.

In the environments/development.rb, config.cache_classes = false.

Is there any way to extend Devise or override the function that specifies which is the login url for devise_cas_authenticatable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to redefine the 'new' action in the cas gem in a lib file:

1. Create a new file in /lib called
   devise_cas_authenticatable_extender.rb, or any other name you like.

   ```
   touch lib/devise_cas_authenticatable_extender.rb
   ```
2. Copy and paste the following
   text inside

   ```
   # This library is necessary for CAS authentication to work dynamically
   # Note: if called from application controller it raises a circular dependency ...
   # ... error when using thin (not with rails s)
   # It has to be required in every controller that uses CAS authentication
   Devise::CasSessionsController.class_eval do
     # We redefine the behaviour of the new action to be dynamic
     def new
       domain=request.protocol + ((request.port.blank? || request.port==80) ? request.host : "#{request.host}:#{request.port}") # Production and development
       servicio=domain+"/users/service"
       servicio=servicio.gsub(':', '%3A').gsub('/', '%2F') # This can probably be done with URI
       url="https://your_cas_server_domain/#{session[:dynamic_url_path]}/login?service=#{servicio}"
       redirect_to url
     end
   end
   ```
3. Insert the following in the controller(s) that use
   authentication (note: if you use application_controller.rb, you may
   get a circular_dependency error, I didn't get into solving that
   since I don't use application_controller.rb for session stuff).

   ```
   # This library is necessary for CAS authentication to work dynamically
   # Note: if called from application controller it raises a circular dependency ...
   # ... error when using thin (not with rails s)
   # It has to be required in every controller that uses CAS authentication
   require 'devise_cas_authenticatable_extender'
   ```
4. Somewhere in your code, set the session[:dynamic_url_path] variable to something that makes sense in your project, like:

   ```
   session[:dynamic_url_path] = request.path_parameters[:your_routes_path_variable_here]
   ```
5. That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

I've used this solution and I was getting the Circular dependency error with the application running in production environment (because of the eager_load configuration).

Finally I got it working inserting the require 'devise_cas_authenticatable_extender' in the config/environments.rb file.